# Debug of Nuts & Bolts Problem python code

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, quicksort, divide-and-conquer

I tried to write the code to solve Nuts & Bolts Problem by using quicksort(?), but it does not work well. The most confusing part for me is the returning point of recursion. How can I modify it and is there any tip to considering the returning point of recursion?

Nuts & Bolts Problem:
Given a set of n nuts of different sizes and n bolts of different sizes. There is a one-one mapping between nuts and bolts. Match nuts and bolts efficiently.
Constraint: Comparison of a nut to another nut or a bolt to another bolt is not allowed. It means nut can only be compared with bolt and bolt can only be compared with nut to see which one is bigger/smaller.
Other way of asking this problem is, given a box with locks and keys where one lock can be opened by one key in the box. We need to match the pair.

```
def smallerThanPartition(nuts, p):
    lowN = []
    for i in range(0, len(nuts)):
        if p > nuts[i]:
            lowN.append(nuts[i])
    return lowN

def largerThanPartition(nuts, p):
    highN = []
    for i in range(0, len(nuts)):
        if p < nuts[i]:
            highN.append(nuts[i])
    return highN

def ALG5(nuts, bolts, partition):
    if(len(bolts) <= 1):
        print('nuts + bolts = '+ str(nuts + bolts))
        return nuts + bolts
    else:
        lowB = []
        highB = []
        a = []
        b = []
        lowN = []
        highN = []
        for i in range(0, len(nuts)):
            if nuts[partition] > bolts[i]:
                lowB.append(bolts[i])
                lowN = smallerThanPartition(nuts, nuts[partition])
            else:
                highB.append(bolts[i])
                highN = largerThanPartition(nuts, nuts[partition])

        a = ALG5(lowN, lowB, len(lowN) / 2)
        b = ALG5(highN, highB, len(highN) / 2)
        return a + nuts[partition] + b

if __name__ == "__main__":

    nuts = [1, 3, 5, 2, 44, 6]
    bolts = [5, 2, 6, 44, 1, 3]
    n = len(nuts)
    partition = n / 2
    print(ALG5(nuts, bolts, partition))
```

the result of the above code is

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 6, 44, 44]
[1, 3, 5, 2, 44, 6]
[5, 2, 6, 44, 1, 3]
```

the ideal result is

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 44]
[1, 3, 5, 2, 44, 6]
[5, 2, 6, 44, 1, 3]
```

Comment: What is "Nuts & Bolts Problem"?

Comment: sorry, i added the explanation about Nuts & Bolts Problem

Comment: When I run the code in both python 2 and python 3, it produces an error and not the result you say it produces.

Comment: @PaulHankin what error was that?

Comment: I think there's a flaw in your logic - a key idea behind QuickSort is that the pivot element is moved to its final place towards the end of each partitioning step, before the recursive calls.